# CSV decode in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, base64

I am trying to read the CSV values in apex. I am getting the base64 file in apex, however not able to read the data.

**Helper method:**

```
uploadHelper: function(component, event) {

        var fileInput = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
        // get the first file using array index[0]  
        var file = fileInput[0];

        var action = component.get("c.passFile");
        // create a FileReader object 
        var objFileReader = new FileReader();
        // set onload function of FileReader object   
        objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
            var fileContents = objFileReader.result; 
            action.setParams({ file : encodeURIComponent(objFileReader.result) } );
            action.setCallback(self, function(actionResult) {
                console.log((actionResult.getReturnValue()));
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);            
        });

        objFileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }
```

Class:

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static void passFile(String file)
    {
        //System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error,'Inside Apex '+ file);
        String myFile = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(file, 'UTF-8');
        System.debug('Inside Apex '+myFile);

    }
```

Result:

Inside Apex

> data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,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

I tried decoding using same with "https://www.base64decode.org/", it works perfectly fine. However I am unable to read the data in apex. May be I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take data and base-64 decode it:

```
String myFile = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file.split(',')[1]).toString();
```

Alternatively, you could have decoded it in JavaScript and sent the string in directly.

---

Also, do not encode the data:

```
    objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
        var fileContents = objFileReader.result; 
        action.setParams({ file : objFileReader.result });
        action.setCallback(self, function(actionResult) {
            console.log((actionResult.getReturnValue()));
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);            
    });
```

Comment: getting "System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1", probably decoding at javascript is better option I believe as you said.

Comment: @Ajay You shouldn't be using encodeURIComponent on the client side, though.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file).toString()
```

Instead of:

```
EncodingUtil.urlDecode(file, 'UTF-8')
```

- [Encoding Util class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)
- [Blob Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm)

Comment: I am getting "Illegal assignment from Blob to String" error.

Comment: Updated with a link to documentation, that should help you move in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Finally decoded at client side:

```
b64DecodeUnicode: function (component, str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
    }
```

Thanks @sfdcfox for the suggestion.

Comment: If you used someone else's answer, accept their answer, do not post your own answer to take credit.

Comment: @gNerb: I don't take any credit here, Please be gentle when you are replying. I don't run behind the credits. I took the sfdcfox suggestion and however I implemented on my own. If that is not appropriate, you can tell me that in a gentle way. Please be noted that, I also like to contribute to community, not for credit. I am really not happy the way you have replied here. If Admin asks, I can give whatever credit I have with me to anyone.

Comment: Try to understand that if everyone posted an answer after "implementing it on their own" then everyone would be answering their own questions all the time. Of course you "implemented it on your own". SFDC Fox gave you the solution. You need to click the check mark next to his answer, not post your own.

Comment: You need to understand here, that I posted my answer because someone else will be benefited not for the credit. That is what I wanted to clarify. I did not accept post as answer. Please check.